# Binary classifier via Mahalonobis distance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, binary-data, distance, mahalanobis

In a recent conversation with a colleague at univerity, they mentioned that for a certain problem, we can "just use a binary classifier". When I inquired as to how they would train, they said "No training. Just use Mahalonobis distance".

I'm confused, because I am not really sure what/how they mean. As I understand it, you always need labelled data for a binary classification. Once we have this labelled data, we can train with some algorithm in order to get a classifier. What did my colleague mean?

Comment: Just ask your colleague for clarification.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat I cant, he was a big wig who was only visiting us.

Comment: One could make several different educated guesses, depending on what information is available in the problem.  Could you elaborate on what this "certain problem" is?

Comment: So this is how I'd decipher the message: Mahalonobis distance is closely related to multivariate normal distribution. There exists some value `x` such that any gaussian r.v. (with given covariation matrix) will have Mahalonobis distance to the mean less than `x` with very high probability (think [multivariate] confidence intervals). So all you need is to determine that gaussian's parameters. You can a) estimate it from samples (that's learning, actually); b) come up with some values based on domain knowledge. The described approach is quite similar to Quadratic Discriminant Analysis.

Comment: @whuber Hi whuber. From certain parts of an image, we know that some patches are of class 1, some other patches are of class 0. Now, we would like to classify the remaining patches as either 0 or 1, based on this data. It is in how we go about doing this, that he mentioned that we dont need to train, and 'just use mahalonobis distance'. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmaley.exe Right, if we were to estimate the parameters of the multivariate gaussians, then that *is* learning right? That was my point to him. Anyway, let us say we go with that method, at this point, does that mean that once we learn the parameters of the two classes, that we just compute the probability that a new sample belongs to each class, and pick the class that gave the highest probability? Thanks.

Comment: @Tarantula, yes, you're correct. Mahalonobis distance is defined by positive-definite matrix, so you need to get it somehow. In QDA we pick the most probable class out of 2 candidates. If you have only one class and need to find outliers (i.e. for fraud detection, though it's a terrible example for such a toy model), you use something like confidence intervals: just like in 1D case there's three-sigma rule (or more sigmas); I think this question may be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143377/3-sigma-rule-for-multivariate-normal-distribution

Comment: Tarantula, do you perhaps have other (co-registered) images of covariate information? If not--if all you have are these binary images and have not made strong assumptions about how they are generated--it is difficult to see how any version of Mahalanobis distance would offer a justifiably good classifier.

Comment: @whuber I think so... Ill just tell you what we have: We have a whole bunch of image patches that correspond to corn stalks/plants. Some other patches in the database correspond to just soil. So now given a new image, we chop it up into patches. Then, we wish to associate each new patch as wither most likely belonging to the corn plant, or the soil. To this, my colleague said 'just use mahalonobis distance, since this is just a binary classification problem'. When I said 'but dont you need to  train?', he said flatly, 'No training. Just use mahalonobis distance'... this is the whole story...

Comment: Didn't they simply mean k nearest neighbors..?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like k-nearest neighbors (kNN) with Mahalanobis distance as the distance metric to determine the nearest neighbors.

In mathematical analysis and topology, a “metric” is a function that inputs two points and outputs a non-negative number. There are formal properties of a metric function, but the key is that it behaves like we think distances should behave.

Consequently, when we talk about the “nearest” neighbors in kNN, it is on us to determine the sense in which points are “near”.

Mahalanobis distance considers the covariance matrix $S$ and mean vector $\bar x$ of your data, and the metric function to find the Mahalanobis distance between $x$ and $y$ is $d_M(x,y)=\sqrt{
(x-\bar x)^TS^{-1}(y-\bar x)
}$.

To find the nearest neighbors to a point $x$, calculate the distances between $x$ and all other points. Then pick the $k$ points that have the smallest value of $d_M$, which have a reasonable interpretation of being “nearest” to $x$.

There isn’t really any training. You just apply the Mahalanobis distance, get the nearest neighbors, and use those to make your prediction, which sounds like what your visitor said.